# The probability of getting exactly $k$ crossings in buffons needle problem

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, geometric-probability

I am studying Buffons needle problem and I am currently trying to derive the probability of getting exactly $k$ crossings for the situation $l > d$ where $l$ is the needle length and $d$ is the distance between the parallell lines.

I have been looking at this link specifically: [Buffon's needle: expected number of intersections & pmf when $l > d$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3013566/buffons-needle-expected-number-of-intersections-pmf-when-l-d)

This has given me more than enough information to derive the probability for $k$ crossings. $k$ ranges from $0$ to $m = \lfloor{l/d}\rfloor$ in integer steps. However, when I try to simulate the needle dropping using Python I get results that vary vastly from the theoretical results (I also know the the convergence towards $\pi$ is very slow for this problem, so maybe that also affects the convergence of probabilities, however some of them are 2-3 times as small) which means *I'm skeptical about my derivation* used in the link which I use to define my theoretical results in Python. I hope some of you can fact check my results here.

Using the notation in the answer from @G Cab, provided in the link (but instead letting $s \sim \mathcal{U}(0,1)$, and also in my case I have used horizontal lines contrary to the vertical lines used in the derivation I provided in this link. I have fact checked this and the derivation stays the same but changing out the cosines for sines in the expressions above if we are just careful with how we define $\theta$ in our new setting. Getting exactly $k$ crossings means that we restrict our $\theta$ in the range $\arcsin\left(\frac{k-s}{r}\right) \leq \theta <\arcsin\left(\frac{(k+1)-s}{r}\right)$.To find the probability I then do the following integration

$$\int_0^1 \int_{\arcsin\left(\frac{k-s}{r}\right)}^{\arcsin\left(\frac{k+1-s}{r}\right)} \frac{1}{\pi/2} d\theta ds$$

Which I then use an integral calculator to evaluate. **Is this the correct way of doing it?** I use this for $0 < k < m$. For $k=m$ I require to split the integral and integrate to $\pi/2$ instead as upper limit for $\theta$. For $k=0$ I instead require to use $0$ as lower limit for $\theta$.

**Also, I wonder whether there's any way to visualize this integral in our sample space.** I am working on getting some nice visualizations in for this problem.
In my previous cases for visualization, it was very easy to visualize how the integrals run for simply calculating the probability of getting a crossing, without considering **exactly** how many crossings I get. This is I suppose the standard problem of asking the probability of a crossing for a long needle.

[image]

For instance in the figure above, I would just integrate under the sine curve towards the first intersection between the graphs, and then under the blue graph from that intersection to $\pi/2$.The derivation can also be found in wikipedia for this.
[image]

In my case, asking for $k$ crossings, we are essentially adding more parallell lines to the curve if I am not mistaken by the results we derived earlier. I think this could be seen much easier if we took the sine on both sides of the constraint on $\theta$.

$\arcsin\left(\frac{k-s}{r}\right) \leq \theta <\arcsin\left(\frac{(k+1)-s}{r}\right)$

giving us

$\frac{k-s}{r} \leq \sin\theta < \frac{(k+1)-s}{r}$

where the LHS is $\sim r^{-1}\mathcal{U}(k-1,k)$ and the RHS $\sim r^{-1}\mathcal{U}(k,k,+1)$.
Hence why I drew those additional horizontal lines to consider during integration (note that I am just using arbitrary values in the figures for the horizontal lines above). **My question now is, how can we visualize this constraint on $\theta$ for $k$ crossings in such a figure I provided above?**

My code used is presented below (with reservation for theoretical results which I am unsure of and have commented out). Please try run the code for yourself to see if there's maybe something obvious I am missing.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random as random
import math


no_of_needles = 10000
r = 3
m = math.ceil(r + 1)

ys = np.arange(1, math.floor(r))
crossings = np.zeros(math.floor(r)+1)

plt.figure(1)
# plot of parallell lines with distance 1 between
for i in range(0,m):
    plt.axvline(i, color = 'black')

def generate_random_colors(m):
    # Generate m random colors in the form of (R, G, B) tuples
    colors = [(random.random(), random.random(), random.random()) for _ in range(m)]
    return colors

colors = generate_random_colors(len(crossings))

ys = np.arange(1, r+1, 1.0)
for i in range(no_of_needles):

    # randomly distributed number of position y in range [0, 1/2]
    y = random.uniform(0, 1)
    # randomly distributed angles in range [0, pi/2]
    theta = random.uniform(0, np.pi/2)
    x_coords = [y, y + r * np.sin(theta)]
    y_coords = [0, r * np.cos(theta)]
    # creating a list starting from floor(y+r) and ending at 0 with integer steps
    y_ns= np.insert(ys, 0, y)
    theta_ns = np.arcsin((y_ns - y) / r)

    #calculate no of crossings
    theta_ns_new = theta_ns.searchsorted(theta)
    no_of_crossings = theta_ns_new - 1

    # make a list of no_of_crossings for a single needle and store in list for plotting at end
    crossings[no_of_crossings] += 1

    plt.plot(x_coords, y_coords, color = colors[no_of_crossings], label = no_of_crossings)

def legend_without_duplicate_labels(figure):
    handles, labels = plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()
    by_label = dict(zip(labels, handles))
    figure.legend(by_label.values(), by_label.keys(), loc='lower right')


legend_without_duplicate_labels(plt.gcf())


""" def theoretical_result(r):
    max_crossings = len(crossings) 
    theor_prb = np.zeros(max_crossings)
    for i in range(1,max_crossings):
        theor_prb[i-1] = 2/np.pi *  r* (-(i-1)/r * np.arcsin((i-1)/r) - np.sqrt(1-((i-1)/r)**2) + i/r * np.arcsin(i/r)+ np.sqrt(1-(i/r)**2))
    theor_prb[max_crossings-1] = (4/np.pi) * r *((np.sqrt(1-((max_crossings-1)/r)**2) - (max_crossings-1)/r * np.arcsin((max_crossings-1)/r)))
    return theor_prb """

plt.title('Needle orientation and positions colored by no of crossings')
plt.figure(2)
# histogram plot of crossings 
""" print(theoretical_result(r))
print([theoretical_result(r)[i]*no_of_needles/crossings[i] for i in range(0,len(crossings))]) """
plt.scatter(np.arange(0,len(crossings)), crossings/no_of_needles, color = 'black', marker = 'o')
""" plt.scatter(np.arange(0,len(crossings)), theoretical_result(r), color = 'orange', marker = 'x')"""
plt.plot(np.arange(0,len(crossings)), crossings/no_of_needles, color = 'red')
plt.title(r'Histogram of crossings')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you simulating the needle drops in Python? Simulating random needle drops is far more tricky than people think. Fairly reasonable sounding methods for simulating the drop give significantly different results. I believe 3Blue1Brown did a video on it (though not on their own channel, IIRC - it may have been on numberphile, or some other math vlogger site).

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thank you. Never thought it was tricky to be honest but maybe I am missing some detail. What makes it tricky in your opinion? Either way, I generate a randomly distributed $s$ together with a randomly distrubted angle $\theta$ defined on the range I provided in the problem description. Since the needle length is given I can determine the other end point. Therafter I just use the condition I provided above to determine if a needle has crossed a line or not. Yes I recall numberphile doing a video on it. I will add my code above.

Comment: Have a look at [Bertrand's Paradox](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Bertrand_paradox_(probability)) and, yeah, [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mZBwsm6B280)'s the Numberphile interview with 3Blue1Brown.

Comment: @SammyBlack - thanks for backing up my vague recollections with solid links. @ Tanamas - those links explain what I am referring to. The idea of dropping needles "at random" is vague. Different interpretations of what "at random" means here could lead to significantly different distributions, which in turn would lead to different outcomes. When comparing your results to others results, one of the things you need to check is that your interpretation of "at random" and theirs are equivalent. Whether this is your problem, I do not know. But it is something to check.

Comment: @SammyBlack @ Paul Sinclair Thank you I've been reading the article and its truly interesting. I have tried to think about what *random* really means for my case. Also reading about “Jaynes's solution” makes me feel like both translation and rotation symmetry exist for my definition. I know that Jaynes solution is not directly a proof that there might be an issue on the well-defineness of random in your problem, but he proposes a nice argument to be honest. I have tried to look on the web and it doesn't seem like Bertrands paradox is a problem for Buffons needle.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I also understand that maybe my definition of random was vague when I first proposed the problem. It's similiar to what is done with the example in Bertrands paradox. You can see it as choosing a midpoint together with an angle, or a random radius of a circle together with a randomly distributed fractional part of that circle which constitutes the midpoint of the needle. (both of which seem equivalent in their definition). I'm unsure if this is a problem in my case after reading the article from @ SammyBlack, but needle-ss to say (no pun intended) a very interesting topic.

Comment: The vagueness isn't *your* doing - it is built into conventional "light" discussions of Buffon's needle. What you need to do is go further in depth on Buffon's needle to determine how exactly the needle drops should be distributed to get the desired results. Then see if your method provides that distribution. If not, then you have *an* issue with your approach (there may be others). If so, then there is some other source for the discrepancy.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Seems reasonable. I will do some more research to see if there are any other interpretations, and see how I need to define the problem to get the desired result as you stated. Thank you for your help!